# How can I make Openlayers3 tiles fade in as they load?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm using some tile layers in Openlayers3 (3.5.0), of different kinds (XYZ and plain TileImage). I want to make the tiles fade in as they are loaded.

I have found that [the tile sources I'm using](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileImage.html) emit a `tileloadend` event (also `tileloadstart` and `tileloaderror`) and I can successfully catch this. Its event object gives me access to the corresponding [`ImageTile`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.ImageTile.html) object, which has methods to get its coordinates and to get an image element.

The image element is a DOM image element in my case, but which is not actually attached to the DOM. It's not on the page -- it's just the source which is then loaded into the canvas element, as far as I can tell. So I'm not sure this actually helps me to fade it in.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The image element is used to draw the tile onto the map canvas. Right now tile fading is not supported, see https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/594